# Is there a way to get the generic typeinfo

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have this classes:

```
class Test<K,V> {}

class Test1 : Test<int, string> {}
```

Is there a way to get the info from an instance of `Test1` that it behaves on `int, string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, you want *generic arguments* of the *base type*:

```
  using System.Reflection;

  ...  

  Type[] generics = typeof(Test1)
    .BaseType               // Test<K, V>
    .GetGenericArguments(); // {K, V}

  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", generics.Select(t => t.Name)));
```

Outcome:

```
  Int32, String
```

If you have an *instance*, use `.GetType()`:

```
  Test1 myTest = ...

  Type[] generics = myTest
    .GetType()              // Test1
    .BaseType               // Test<K, V>
    .GetGenericArguments(); // {K, V}
```